# Click placemarker using touchscreen X and Y

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers, google-earth-plugin, google-maps-api-2

I'm using the Google Maps API and trying to drive the GE Plugin from a touch screen. I get back an X, and Y for a given touch and can do something like:

```
var targetElement = document.elementFromPoint(data.x, scaledY);
if (null != targetElement) {
   var event = $.Event ("click");
   $(targetElement).trigger (event);
}
```

to raise an event for a button on the screen but this does not click on placemarkers within the GE Plugin. Is there an easy way to fire a click event on these markers?

Many thanks for any help you can provide.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK you can't manually raise any events for any of the objects in the Google Earth Api, you can only add an event listener for them as either a named or anonymous method.

However you could certainly simulate the default click behaviour (opening the balloon, fly to, etc) for placemarks using a custom method.

I have done this before and it simply required that each feature had a unique ID within the plugin (set either via the api or in kml). I then used this as a way to target the feature based on it's id.

In your example presuming `targetEvement` could also have a corresponding ID set, then you could use this technique to simulate a 'click' like so.

```
var targetElement = document.elementFromPoint(data.x, scaledY);
if (null != targetElement) {
   var event = $.Event ("click");
   $(targetElement).trigger (event);

   simulateClick(targetElement);
}

var simulateClick = function (element) {
  // presuming 'ge' references the plugin
  // we create a feature balloon based on the placemark
  var id = element.attr('id');
  var placemark = ge.getElementById(id); // corresponding placemark
  var balloon = ge.createFeatureBalloon();
  balloon.setFeature(placemark);
  ge.setBalloon(balloon);

  // Update the view in Google Earth to the placemark.
  // if no abstract view is defined you could also use the placemarks
  // latitude and longitude to construct a KmlCamera object.
  ge.getView().setAbstractView(placemark.getAbstractView());
}
```

Comment: If you load your kml via fetchKml then you will need to use var placemark = ge.getElementByUrl(url + '#' + id) where url is obviously the URL of your kml file